# How to get current worker connections being used by nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Nginx.conf, looks like this

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

```
events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
```

The command `ulimit -n` gives the number of worker connections available, I want the number which is currently being used by nginx.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ngx_http_stub_status_module` module provides access to basic status information.

```
location /basic_status {
    stub_status;
}
```

This configuration creates a simple web page with basic status data which may look like as follows:

```
Active connections: 291 
server accepts handled requests
 16630948 16630948 31070465 
Reading: 6 Writing: 179 Waiting: 106
```

Source: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html

Comment: Is there a way to get this information from terminal, rather than making nginx serve a page?

Comment: I'm not aware of another way to get it. You can wget/curl http://localhost/basic_status from terminal.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Is there a way to find precisely the number of workers (or worker connections) currently being used?

Answer (score 0):

To check all connection

```
sudo netstat -tupn
```

To check all established connection

```
sudo netstat -tupn | grep ESTABLISHED
```

For count all established connection

```
sudo netstat -tupn | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

Check wait connection to use **WAIT** instead of **ESTABLISHED**